# Elasticsearch much slower when returning all results

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, query-performance

I have about 20,000 documents stored in elastic search, at about 200kb each.

I have a search which has 733 hits total, I'm running that takes about 50ms to complete when returning 10 results.

If I set the size to 1000 so that it returns all results, the search takes 3-5 seconds to return.

Normally I would see that this is because it has to continue searching until it finds all of them, which takes extra time. However when returning 10 results only, the search still says 733 hits in total, so it already knows which documents are to be returned!

Note that I am not returning the _source field here, all I want it the list of _ids back, so I can't imagine that it would have to read any more data from the disk, as all the _ids are surely stored in the indices anyway.

Am I missing something in the way this works?

(My _ids are guids that we use internally).

EDIT: Since posting I've re-indexed with two changes to the mapping:

- Set _source to false, so now the actual documents aren't stored.
- Changed the index for the field that I was searching on to be not_analyzed.

This solves the problem, now I'm getting all 733 _ids back in ~50ms. Not sure which change solved it though. I'll take one of them back out and re-index.

Answer (score 0):

It will take that Time. Because it need to fetch all data from ES and calculate score for your query.
Try
1)set fields to not analyzed which you Don search in.
2)change the store type of ES from simplfs to mmaps..  ( mention "index.store.type:mmaps"  in elasticsearch.yml..) 
3)configure less shard as much possible.. Shard more must be equal to move on nodes you gonna use..